# UITableCell turning blank after clicked

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Im using a regular uitableview with regular uitablecells on it with some text and an image on them. When a cell is clicked I perform tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath:, in the end I call [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES]; and everything works fine. But in the meantime before the next view loads its contents from the web, the clicked cell turns completely blank. Any clue on that?

Comment: can you post the related code? Especially the `didSelect...` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`-implementations

Comment: As @thomas wrote, we cannot help you without the code. Write it here, so we can found a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your problem is that you don’t want to show the touched UITableCellView as selected you can try `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;`

Maybe if the problem is the load of the new UIView you can use NSThread and detach the process from the main thread.